# Issue installing Ubuntu 16.04.2 on second SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd

**Background:** I have a computer with a 500GB SSD and a 250GB SSD (both Samsung EVO 850). Windows 10 already sits on the 500GB and I wanted to install Ubuntu on the 250GB. I used Rufus to format a bootable USB with the Ubuntu 16.04.2 iso file. I booted the computer from that usb, followed the directions for the default install, and specified to install it on (what I thought was) the 250. When I restarted my computer, I saw that the installation was actually installed on the 500GB drive where Windows 10 resides. I have no idea why this happened, but since nothing within Windows was affected. Below is the list of boot devices, you can see Ubuntu and Windows sitting on the same drive.

[image]

My second attempt, I made sure to carefully check that I specified the correct drive to install Ubuntu to. I stepped through the manual partition process. During that, I saw my 250GB SSD under /dev/sdb, and 250GB of free space. I partitioned that free space as follows.

- 8GB Swap (primary - EXT4)
- 30GB root / (logical - EXT4)
- 210GB /home (logical - EXT4)

I also made sure to select the 250GB drive in the **Device for boot loader installation** section.

The install happened without any problems and I restarted to a boot menu, selected the 250GB drive. When I did this, I got a [**reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in boot device**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTdAP.png) message.

**My Questions:**

1. What did I do wrong or what should I have done differently?
2. How can I remove the Ubuntu that is sitting on my 500GB disk?

I know this is a lot of information but if you would like more, please ask and I'll happily provide.

**Edits:**

1. I actually booted the **ubuntu (P0: Samsung...)** drive and found that this is the ubuntu that I installed during my second attempt. However, I'm confused why this isn't linked to the 250GB drive when ubuntu thinks it is.

[image]

2. Ubuntu shows that it is mounted in one of the partitions of the windows drive (Partition 2: EFI System mounted at /boot/efi). What does this mean and should I leave this mount?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: its because of the UEFI boot, .it has to install in the UEFI partition, well the boot part of the Linux system. If you wanted to not have it do that I, I really don't know how to remove it from the UEFI partition now, but maybe you can look that up on google .. then .. install it again but disconnect the windows drive first ... then install it with only the 250gb drive installed ... it will fully install to the 250gb drive because the 500gb wont be available to it ... then you may have to use the UEFI / quick menu to select the linux drive to boot to it, like mine is F11 it brings a boot menu

Comment: I may be wrong on this .. lol I'm new to UEFI systems myself but I think that is the reason .. and I know the easiest way around it would be to install Ubuntu with the 500gb drive disconnected from the pc so only the 250 drive is installed. .. but now that its installed in the uefi partition .. not sure it is that straight forward anymore :(

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI